# how to insert images into mysql using html,servlet

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to insert 3 images in `mysql` table using html and `servlet` but it store only one image.

Here is html form.

```
<form action="datahandler.java" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
<input  maxlength="100" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder=""  />
<input type="file" id="files"  name="image1" accept="image/*" /> 
<input type="file" id="files"  name="image2" accept="image/*" /> 
<input type="file" id="files"  name="image3" accept="image/*" /> 
</form>
```

when i upload image and send it to server--datahandler.java

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;


 @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177216) // upto 16 MB
public class DataHandler extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection conn=null;
        String dbPath = "";
        String username = "";
        String password = "";

        String name=request.getParameter("name");

        // Create a new file upload handler
        InputStream inputStream = null; 

        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
        Part parts1 = request.getPart("image1");
        Part parts2 = request.getPart("image2");
        Part parts3 = request.getPart("image3");

         if (parts1 != null) 
        {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(parts1.getName());
            System.out.println(parts1.getSize());
            System.out.println(parts1.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = parts1.getInputStream();
        }
         if (parts2 != null) 
        {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(parts2.getName());
            System.out.println(parts2.getSize());
            System.out.println(parts2.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = parts2.getInputStream();
        }
         if (parts3 != null) 
        {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(parts3.getName());
            System.out.println(parts3.getSize());
            System.out.println(parts3.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = parts3.getInputStream();
        }
         if (parts4 != null) 
        {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(parts4.getName());
            System.out.println(parts4.getSize());
            System.out.println(parts4.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = parts4.getInputStream();
        }


          try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbPath, username, password);

           PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into user(name,image1,image2,image3) values(?,?,?,?)");

           pst.setString(1,name);


            if (inputStream != null)
            {
                // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                pst.setBlob(2, inputStream);
            }
            if (inputStream != null)
            {
                // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                pst.setBlob(3, inputStream);
            }
            if (inputStream != null)
            {
                // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                pst.setBlob(4, inputStream);
            }

           int i = pst.executeUpdate();  
              if(i!=0){  
                out.println("Record has been inserted");  
                   request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp").forward(request, response);

              }  
              else{  
                out.println("failed to insert the data"); 
                request.getRequestDispatcher("failed.jsp").forward(request, response);
               }  
        }
       catch(Exception e){
            out.print(e);
        }
    finally{
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ImageStoreToDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

    }

  }
```

the Servlet is getting all three images System prints its info but when it store to database image3 is get stored in image1 column and image2 and image3 are empty column..please give solution on this..

Comment: I noticed that you have used the same inputStream for three `setBlob ` method invocations, how about using three different inputStreams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you set to the same InputStream all the parts. You must create different InputStream variables like:

`InputStream inputStream1 = parts1.getInputStream();
InputStream inputStream2 = parts2.getInputStream();
InputStream inputStream3 = parts3.getInputStream();`

And when you set the values in the `pst.setBlob(...)` you do the same.
Otherwise you will be setting to each column the same Image. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry about the code, it looks disordered but it is fine. Just pay attention to the “;”

Comment: No problem! You may mark it as “answered” so people can find it too.